# redirect every request to index.php and interpret the request

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, interpretation

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.8.
How should I configure .htaccess to redirect every request do index.php?

I'd like to have URLs like those of stackoverflow or facebook, as: http://mywebsite.com/fancypage
where fancypage isn't a directory on the server but just a parameter.

So I thought I needed to redirect every request to a php page, where some code can interpret the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] string. Is this the right way? will $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] still be available after the redirection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to the .htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

It will send all requests (except for existing files/dirs) to index.php.

The original request will be available in the `request` param.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#skip existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#everything else goes to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [L]
```

Comment: thank you, your code fits the bill! anyway i managed to produce a simpler code which fulfils my basic needs and look like this:
`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(products|admin|support|info|etc)/?$ index.php?req=$1 [NC][L]`

Comment: i tried to remove the RewriteCond so to match any query.. but i reckon that php include() can't work anymore. is there a workaround? i don't want the user to access the include files..

Comment: @user1168006 I don't understand the question: can you clarify what you mean

Comment: i'd like to match ANY query string and always redirect the users to index.php
BUT I need the php function include() to be able to load the files. Maybe there's a way to restrict access to the root subfolders for the users but not the server itself?

Comment: @user1168006  The current `RewriteCond` only exclude requests (that originated externally) for existing files or directories. AFAIK, the php include function is not processed within apache, so .htacces rules will not affect it. However, if there is something that is not working, please describe what URL you are testing, the desired outcome and actual incorrect outcome. A new post might be better as it's hard to fit much (and no formattting) in comments.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`
`RewriteRule . index.php?request=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]`
Oh now I get it! the request for .css and .js and image files and php scripts for ajax calls FROM THE CLIENT are all redirected, if I use those rules! I tested the include() function and it works fine.

so i considered adding this rule
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)`
but i still the ajax requests were redirected. 
So I guess I'll simply deny access to the include folder..

Answer (score 1):

What you are interested in is Apache's url_rewrite function. I suggest you visit these two links and research it a bit:

- [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
- [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction! i made it =)